# What does keras model.predict output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential

I've built an LSTM model (see below) and trained it. My loss function is binary cross entropy as I'm doing binary classification. The training y data is a set of 0's and 1's.

When I run `model.predict(x_test_scaled)` I get a set single series with values ranging between 0 and 1. I'm guessing this is a probability, but is it the probability that the output = 0 or that the output = 1?

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=512, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    

model.add(Dense(264),  activation = 'tanh')

model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  
The various documentation on Keras and modeling in general describe how to interpret the output.  We expect you to have read enough to have a specific question with reference to that knowledge.

Comment: I've read the documentation on this website. [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) It doesn't actually cover how to interpret the output. It does say "Generates output predictions for the input samples.", but that doesn't really help.

Comment: That is why I referred you to more than one document.  You need to read about what is produced by the specific class of model you trained.

Comment: I'm happy to read documentation, and would appreciate a link to the documentation that covers this if you know this information.

Comment: ... which is also off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I have no way of knowing what documents match your reading level, learning styles, etc.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I appreciate you don't feel the question is posed correctly, or in the right place, but in summary your comments are "go and find the answer to your question, it's out there on the internet... somewhere". I think we can both agree that this is not constructive.

Comment: Again, please refer to the posting guidelines to understand the chartered purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have a link to the posting guidelines?

Comment: I already *gave* you the central link.  When you signed up for your account, you were given the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That was a joke. Have some fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite rusty with ANNs, but maybe I can help.

`Model.predict` passes the input vector through the model and returns the output tensor for each datapoint.
Since the last layer in your model is a single Dense neuron, the output for any datapoint is a single value. And since you didn't specify an activation for the last layer, it will default to linear activation.

Because you're solving a classification problem, you probably need `sigmoid` activation. If memory doesn't betray me, I believe you can get-by by solving it as a multi-class classification with 2 classes (essentially 2 output neurons with softmax activation). Essentially, line activation is not suited for classification problems.

**MORE NOTES: understanding your model**

If you want to understand the output you're getting, you have to understand the task you're training the model to solve.

With each data-point, you tell the model `the output for this is 1` or `the output for this is 0`. But it looks at the output not as a class for the input, but rather as a value from the range [0,1]. and it's being trained to emit values in this range.

Have a look at the training `y` tensor. Let's assume an output of `0` matches the first class, and an output of `1` matches the second class.

In this case, the more certain your model is about the input, the farther from 0.5 its output will be.

So, a value of `0.1` means your model is sort-of certain it belongs to `class 1` (closer to output value `0`).
If the output is `0.9999` then it thinks the input belongs to `class 2` very high certainty (output is very close to 1).
If the output, on the other hand, is something like `0.45` (very close to `0.5`), then the model thinks "maybe the input belongs to class 1, but I'm totally not sure about it.

Hope this helped a little, I'll also upvote any answer that's more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely outputting the accuracy of your AI, the higher the better the accuracy of your AI is, you can use this to tweek some settings in your training process to get a higher accuracy.

Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: model.evaluate outputs the accuracy and loss. model.predict is used to predict your test set or validation, whatever you want to predict. However accuracy is not a good metric everytime.